# If function and using dots from a graph

Tags: r

I am making a graph using these datas:

```
Upper_limit_graph_wt <- (((log(8)/50:5000)-log(d_wt))/log(g_wt))
Lower_limit_graph_wt <- (((log(1/8)/50:5000)-log(d_wt))/log(g_wt))
plot(Upper_limit_graph_wt, type="l", ylim=g_range, xlim=range(0:5000), ann=FALSE, col="pink")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(Lower_limit_graph_wt, type="l", ylim=g_range, xlim=range(0:5000), ann=FALSE, col="gold")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(Total_count, (Alt_count/Total_count), pch=16, ann=FALSE, ylim=g_range, xlim=range(0:5000), col="dark green")
```

I can't add an image but I basically get a graph with 2 curves and 1 dot.
The coordinates for my dot are x=Total_count and y=(Alt_count/Total_count)

However I don't seem to be able to add the function if else

When I do :

```
if((Total_count, (Alt_count/Total_count))> Upper_limit_graph)print"Fail"
```

It tells me "," was unexpected

How do I make it print something when my dot is above my curves?

Thanks

Comment: `print` is a function in R and not a keyword. Please study `help("print")`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `text` to add the text to your plot. Please see as follows:

```
d_wt <- 2
g_wt <- 3

Upper_limit_graph_wt <- (((log(8) / 50:5000) - log(d_wt)) / log(g_wt))
Lower_limit_graph_wt <- (((log(1/8)/50:5000) - log(d_wt)) / log(g_wt))
g_range <- seq_along(Upper_limit_graph_wt)

plot(c(Lower_limit_graph_wt, Upper_limit_graph_wt), xlim = range(g_range), type = "n")
lines(Lower_limit_graph_wt)
lines(Upper_limit_graph_wt)

Total_count <- 1000
Alt_count <- -600
points(Total_count, Alt_count/Total_count, cex = 2, col = "blue", pch = 19)

text(2000, -0.62, 
     ifelse((Alt_count / Total_count > Upper_limit_graph_wt[Total_count]), "Fail", ""),  
     col = "red")
```

Output:
[image]